# Load an array to select2 dynamically

Tags: jquery-select2

I'm trying to load an array to select2 dynamically using js below:

```
var dsDow = [
   { id: "0", text: "Sun" },
   { id: "1", text: "Mon" },
   { id: "2", text: "Tue" },
   { id: "3", text: "Wed" },
   { id: "4", text: "Thu" },
   { id: "5", text: "Fri" },
   { id: "6", text: "Sat" }
];

var inputDow = document.createElement("select");
inputDow.classList.add('select2');
inputDow.classList.add('form-select');
inputDow.setAttribute('id', 'inputDow');
inputDow.setAttribute('name', 'inputDow');
inputDow.setAttribute('tabindex', '1');
inputDow.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');
inputDow.setAttribute('required', 'true');

$('#inputDow').select2({
   data: dsDow,
   tags: true,
   placeholder: "Select Days",
   escapeMarkup: function (markup)
   {
       return markup;
   }
});

action_container.appendChild(inputDow);
```

but it doesn't to load the array to the select2, what did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the dynamically created select to the container with appendChild before initializing select2.

```js
var dsDow = [{
    id: "0",
    text: "Sun"
  },
  {
    id: "1",
    text: "Mon"
  },
  {
    id: "2",
    text: "Tue"
  },
  {
    id: "3",
    text: "Wed"
  },
  {
    id: "4",
    text: "Thu"
  },
  {
    id: "5",
    text: "Fri"
  },
  {
    id: "6",
    text: "Sat"
  }
];

var inputDow = document.createElement("select");
inputDow.classList.add('select2');
inputDow.classList.add('form-select');
inputDow.setAttribute('id', 'inputDow');
inputDow.setAttribute('name', 'inputDow');
inputDow.setAttribute('tabindex', '1');
inputDow.setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple');
inputDow.setAttribute('required', 'true');

var action_container = document.getElementById('action_container');
action_container.appendChild(inputDow);
$('select.select2').css('width', '100%'); // only to a better view in snippet

$('#inputDow').select2({
  data: dsDow,
  tags: true,
  placeholder: "Select Days",
  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-rc.0/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<div id="action_container"></div>
```